# How to modify duplicated rows in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a DataFrame (that I sorted by some priority criterion) with a "`name`" column. Few names are duplicated, and I want to append a simple indicator to the duplicates.

E.g.,

```
'jones a'
... 
'jones a'    # this should become 'jones a2'
```

To get the subset of duplicates, I could do

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['name'], take_last=True), 'name']
```

However, I think the `apply` function does not allow for `inplace` modification, right? So what I basically ended up doing is:

```
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['name'], take_last=True), 'name'] = \
df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['name'], take_last=True), 'name'].apply(lambda x: x+'2')
```

But my feeling is that there might be a better way. Any ideas or tips? I would really appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Note that your solution only works if there is a maximum of one duplicate. Also, you should be able to replace everything after the `=` with `df.name.duplicated(take_last=True).apply...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
# sample data
d = pandas.DataFrame(
    {'Name': ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'bill', 'fred', 'fred', 'joe', 'larry'],
     'ShoeShize': [8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 11, 10, 12]
    }
)

>>> d.groupby('Name').Name.apply(lambda n: n + (np.arange(len(n))+1).astype(str))
0      bob1
1      bob2
2      bob3
3     bill1
4     fred1
5     fred2
6      joe1
7    larry1
```

This appends an indicator to all.  If you want to append the indicator to only those after the first, you can do it with a little special casing:

```
>>> d.groupby('Name').Name.apply(lambda n: n + np.concatenate(([''], (np.arange(len(n))+1).astype(str)[1:])))
0      bob
1     bob2
2     bob3
3     bill
4     fred
5    fred2
6      joe
7    larry
dtype: object
```

If you want to use this to replace the original names just do `d.Name = ...` where `...` is the expression shown above.

You should think about why you're doing this.  It is usually better to have this sort of information in a separate column than smashed into a string.

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good solution! The problem is that I want to merge and update DataFrames that come from different sources. I thought about taking more "first name letters", but some sources only have 1 first name letter, so that would not be an option ...

Comment: Thanks, you could also use `np.arange(2, len(n) + 1)`, that seems clearer to me.